# AWS Glue Job: SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

i have a large volume of parquet files in S3 and Glue script created reads the parquet files and creates Dynamic dataframe. when i try to call show on the dynamic dataframe , job fails with below error

SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException saying that the parquet column cannot be converted.

I have tried the ResolveChoice Function to convert the datatype of the column , but i still get the same error

Code below:

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
     format_options={},
     connection_type="s3",
     format="parquet",
     connection_options={
         "paths": s3_path_lst,
         "recurse": True,
     },
     transformation_ctx="datasource0",
 )

datasource0.printSchema() 
datasource_dyf = datasource0.resolveChoice(specs=[('NumberOfEmployees', 'cast:int')])
datasource_dyf.printSchema()
datasource_dyf.show()
```

Exception

org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1996)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:232)\nCaused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.constructConvertNotSupportedException(VectorizedColumnReader.java:339)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readIntBatch(VectorizedColumnReader.java:571)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.readBatch(VectorizedColumnReader.java:294)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:295)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:196)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:37)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:159)\n\tat

AWS Glue ResolveChoice should covert the column datatype to String from int , but not sure why it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that all entries in the `NumberOfEmployees` is present and could be casted to non-nullable integer? To solve the challenge, you may either:

- Consider implementing data cleansing before running the invocation for `resolveChoice` function.
- Consider converting the column to nullable integer instead of int if your situation permits.

```py
datasource_dyf = datasource0.resolveChoice(specs=[('NumberOfEmployees', 'cast:int?')])
```